# checking whether c compiler works . . no (libdvbpsi source compile)

Tags: raspberry-pi, vlc, autoconf

I'm trying to compile the latest version of libdvbpsi for a hardware accelerated version of vlc on a raspberry pi (running Raspbian). I used git to clone a repository (git clone git://git.videolan.org/libdvbpsi.git), installed pkg-config, autoconf, libtool and buildessential, and ran the bootstrap but am getting hung up on the configure. I've tried ./configure with a number of arguments (--prefix=/usr, --enable-debug, etc) but they all result in the same error:

``` pi@raspberrypi ~/Downloads/libdvbpsi $ ./configure --prefix=/usr 
checking build system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking host system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking target system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in ``/home/pi/Downloads/libdvbpsi':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See ``config.log' for more details ```

[Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KS1jH7HM103beUEu6H89yARNn7chOl9UItlpcp0vEuI/edit?usp=sharing) is config.log

Been through numerous threads, none seemed to work, would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config log states clearly, that your GCC 4.6.3 has an ICE (internal compiler error). It seems to be broken, which is quite a surprise as you are / configure is compiling a trivial example.

Try to re-install GCC or update it with some packports repository to a newer version. Maybe try Clang from the LLVM projct. Set the C compiler with `CC=<compilerpath>`.

Comment: Awesome, a fresh install fixed the problem. Thanks for the help.